# Powershell Module - Argument Types do not match

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am creating a PS module to determine the username to use in `New-AdUser` based on my companies naming scheme but when I pass i  the firstname and lastname parameters it comes up with an error saying argument types do not match

```
Function Get-ADUsername {
Params(
[String] $FirstName,
[String] $LastName
)

# Determine the length of the first and last names
# Then depending on the outcome change the format of the names to become the username
if(($LastName).length -ge 6 -and ($FirstName).length -ge 2)
{
    $Username = $($Lastname).SubString(0,6) + $($Firstname).SubString(0,2)
}
elseif(($LastName).length -le 6 -and ($FirstName).length -ge 2)
{
    $Username = $($Lastname) + $($Firstname).SubString(0,2)
}
elseif(($LastName).length -le 6 -and ($FirstName).length -le 2)
{
    $Username = $($Lastname).SubString(0,6) + $($Firstname)
}

# Test if the username already exists
# If yes it removes the last letter and adds a number
# It keeps increasing the number depending if the username is in use
Try
{
Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -ErrorAction Stop
$usernameLength = $Username.Length - 1
$Username = $Username.SubString(0,$usernameLength)
[string]$Usernamenumber = "2"
    do
    {
        $Username = $Username + $Usernamenumber
        $Check = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username
        $Usernamenumber++
    }
    while($Check)
}
Catch
{
    break;
}
Return $Username
}
```

Comment: Microsoft Docs on `Get-ADUser` specifies the allowable data for the `-Identity` parameter to the cmdlet. You should ensure that the data you are passing conforms. Also look at whether it might be more appropriate to use the `-Filter` or `-LDAPFilter` parameters instead.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: Actually, what is the actual error that you are getting?

Comment: On a side-note, your script will probably be more efficient if you performs a single user lookup (with a wildcard filter) for all clashing users in AD, rather than going back to AD to check each possibility.  Also, you are explicitly casting `$UserNameNumber` as a string (`[string]$Usernamenumber = "2"`), then incrementing it like a number `$Usernamenumber++`) - explicit typing is rarely needed in PowerShell and is particularly pointless if you're going to ignore it once set.

Comment: Your function will generate 9 character usernames when `$Usernamenumber` hits 10.